# Adding A Soft Delete in Craft 2 Entries

Tags: plugin-development, database, craft2, soft-deletes

I've been thinking of adding a "Soft Delete" or just perhaps a means in which deleting in certain sections (e.g. News) will archive the entry with an update, rather than deleting it.
As I haven't really touched the Craft tables before, while making plugins, I was wondering about the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks for any leads!

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but Craft 3.1 added soft delete support for elements. If you're able to update to the latest it might save you some effort.

Comment: Seeing as Craft 2 is on life support, I agree with Brad - upgrading to Craft 3 might be smarter!